# Show that $F \not = G$ in splitting field of 2 polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $F$ be splitting Field of $x^3 -7 \in \mathbb{Q} [x]$ and let $G$ be the splitting field of 
$$ (x^3-7) (x^2-3) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$$

Show that $F \not = G$

---

Show that $F \not = G$

The roots of $x^3-7$ are

$$\sqrt[3]{7},(\sqrt[3]{7}) w_3^1,(\sqrt[3]{7}) w_3^2  $$

The roots of $x^2-3$ are

$$ \sqrt{3},\sqrt{-3} $$

F by definition is

$$F = \mathbb{Q} \left (\sqrt[3]{7},(\sqrt[3]{7}) w_3,(\sqrt[3]{7}) w_3^2 \right)= \{ f_1+f_2\sqrt[3]{7} +f_3 (\sqrt[3]{7}) w_3 +f_4(\sqrt[3]{7}) w_3^2 ;f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4\in \mathbb{Q} \}$$

Now, call $H$ the splitting field of $x^2-3 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ over $\mathbb{Q}$
So, 
$$H = \mathbb{Q}(-\sqrt{3},\sqrt{3}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}) = \{h_1+h_2 \sqrt{3} : h_1,h_2 \in \mathbb{Q}\} $$

$G$ is a bigger splitting field getting the basis from combinations of $H$ and $F$

so they are

$$\sqrt{3}, \sqrt[3]{7},(\sqrt[3]{7}) w_3,(\sqrt[3]{7}) w_3^2,
\sqrt{3}\sqrt[3]{7},\sqrt{3}(\sqrt[3]{7}) w_3,\sqrt{3}(\sqrt[3]{7}) w_3^2 $$

$G \not \subset F$ [$\therefore$ Not equal]

---

*Its probably easiest just to say $\sqrt[3]{7} \not \in F $ but $\sqrt[3]{7}$ in $G$ and I might have done something wrong in the long way*

Comment: I am getting foggy. I meant $\sqrt{3} \not \in F$  but $\sqrt{3} \in G$

Comment: Anyway, your description of $F$ as four-dimensional vector space is too small (is not a field). Clearly, we must have $\omega_3=\frac{\sqrt[3]7\omega_3}{\sqrt[3]7}\in \Bbb Q[\sqrt[3]7,\sqrt[3]7\omega_3,\sqrt[3]7\omega_3^2]$. Try $1,\sqrt[3]7, \sqrt[3]7\omega_3,\sqrt[3]7\omega_3^2,  \omega_3,\omega_3^2$ as basis